# Application with Branch deep linking shows UIAlertController warning on reopening through deep link

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have successfully implemented deep linking with Branck iOS SDK.

However on re-opening application shows following warning in console:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
>   (UIAlertController: 0x16b00800)

My `AppDelegate` with basic code implementation is:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Branch initialization   
        let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()

        branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:
            { optParams, error in
            if error == nil, let params = optParams
            {
                print("Branch params: ", params.description)
            }
        })

        return true
    }

    // Respond to URI scheme links
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
    {
        print("Branch url URI: ", url)

        // pass the url to the handle deep link call
        Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url)

        return true
    }

    // Respond to Universal Links
    func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
        print("Branch universal link ")

        Branch.getInstance().continueUserActivity(userActivity)

        return true
    }

}
```

How to remove above warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove warning `AppDelegate` must additionally implement `application:willContinueUserActivityWithType` function that will return `true`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: when we see this issue, it's often a conflict with some other SDK you have integrated. Glad you got it resolved for now, but feel free to follow up with our [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) if you have any further questions!

Comment: @AlexBauer Thanks for the link.